# ошибка кодировки при установке библиотек

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

Хотел поучиться писать ботов  и при попытке установить нужные библиотеки столкнулся с такой ошибкой:

> "UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in
> position 17:   character maps to "

устанавливаю через терминал в PyCharm. Ошибка появляется при попытке установить `requests` после `aiogram` и в обратном порядке установки, а так же при попытке обновить `pip`.

Comment: Полный трейс ошибки есть?

Comment: Могут быть проблемы, если имя пользователя у вас на русском и Python установлен внутри AppData внутри папки пользователя. Попробуйте переустановить Python в папку без кириллицы в пути, например в папку `C:\Python`

Comment: Спасибо помогло переустановить все в каталоги без кириллицы.